# Use same type in multiple occurrences

Tags: typescript

Using TypeScript and Angular, I have created the following subscriptions to a HTTP observable:

```
this.movie.getByKeywordIDChrono().subscribe((data: {
  page: number,
  results: object[],
  total_pages: number,
  total_results: number
}) => {

  if (data.total_pages > 1) {
    for (let i = 2; i <= data.total_pages; i++) {
      this.movie.getByKeywordIDChronoNextPage(i).subscribe((data: {
        page: number,
        results: object[],
        total_pages: number,
        total_results: number
      }) => {
        ...
      })
    }
  }

})
```

Both subscriptions have the same type for the `data` object.

How can I use the type created for the data parameter in both instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an interface or a type alias:

```
type MyData =  { // type alias
  page: number,
  results: object[],
  total_pages: number,
  total_results: number
}

this.movie.getByKeywordIDChrono().subscribe((data: MyData) => {

  if (data.total_pages > 1) {
    for (let i = 2; i <= data.total_pages; i++) {
      this.movie.getByKeywordIDChronoNextPage(i).subscribe((data: MyData) => {
        ...
      })
    }
  }

})
```

Or similarly an interface:

```
interface MyData  { 
  page: number,
  results: object[],
  total_pages: number,
  total_results: number
}
```